# Displaying data object in wrong category

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/c1dfuj1s/3/

I have two catgeories : 1970 and 1975.

My question is that even though I am adding a data to 1975, but it adds to 1970.

```
{
   "series": "item6",
   "category": "1975",
   "value": 105
 },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly why this happens, but you can solve it by adding a zero value item 6 to 1970:

```
 {
    "series": "item6",
    "category": "1970",
    "value": 0
},  
    {
    "series": "item6",
    "category": "1975",
    "value": 105
},
```

### Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c1dfuj1s/4/)**

Comment: What if I have totally different two sets of javascript objects? Should I append all zeros? In other words, there are no common objects in two series,i.e, no way to group them, what do you recommend?

Comment: @mystackoverflow if they are truly unrelated, why are you putting them on the same chart?  Charts are generally for comparing related data... You could just create 2 charts and have them side-by-side.

Comment: I mean let's assume only 2 common objects out of 10. How could u handle? The purpose is to show on the bar chart just because of showing these two common objects positions.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, I think appending zero values so all items exist over all categories is the way to go.

Comment: Here is my actual question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539507/plot-bar-stack-category-column